# Given a sequence $x_1=3$ and $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{4-x_n}$, why must the limit of $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ be the same?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> In Abbott's Understanding Analysis, Exercise 2.4.2. asks to prove that the sequence defined by $x_1=3$ and $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{4-x_n}$ converges.

This is not my main question, but I'll include what I've done anyways (the next part is my main concern). What I've done simply by showing that the terms are decreasing, hence monotone. Then, knowing that $x_n$ is decreasing, it must be that $x_1$ is the largest, so our sequence is bounded above. By an argument about the denominator always being positive, i've shown that $0$ is a lower bound. So this sequence is bounded and monotone, hence convergent.

> Now, at the end of the question asks me to show that $\lim x_{n+1}$ must equal $\lim x_n$.

I'm struggling to explain why this is so. What is an intuitive way to think about this? I maybe thinking of things too formally. Supposing $\lim x_n = x$, I wish to show that $\lim x_{n+1} = x$ as well. So for $\epsilon >0$ and choosing $N$ large enough, I have that $n\geq N \implies |x_n-x| < \epsilon$. Now, certainly $n+1>N$, i'm tempted to just substitute $x_{n+1}$ in the previous inequality, but how do I know this will hold?

Comment: You know, $n+1>n\geq N$, so the integer $m = n+1$ satisifies your hypothesis. So $|x_{n+1}-x|<\varepsilon$

Comment: Intuitively, removing the first element of a sequence doesn't change whether the sequence converges, or what it converges to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Intuitive**:

- The sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is the sequence $x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots, x_n,x_{n+1},\dots$
- The sequence $\{x_{n+1}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is the sequence $x_2,x_3, x_4,\dots, x_{n+1}, x_{n+2},\dots$

You can see that apart from $x_1$, the two sequences have identical values. Since limits don't really care what happens at the beginning of a sequence (they only care about what happens to $x_n$ for large values of $n$), the two limits should be the same.

---

**Rigorous**:

Let's prove the statement

> The sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges if and only if the sequence $\{x_{n+1}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges, and their limit, if it exists, is the same.

*Proof, part 1*:

Let $L=\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$, and let $y_n=x_{n+1}$. Also, let $\epsilon > 0$.

From the definition of a limit, there exists some $N$ such that $n>N\implies |x_n-L|<\epsilon$.

Now, let $n>N$. Then, $n+1>N$, and therefore, $|y_n-L| = |x_{n+1}-L|<\epsilon$. Because $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, this proves that

> For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $N$ such that if $n>N$, then $|y_n-L|<\epsilon$.

Therefore, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = L =\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n+1}$$

*Part 2*:

Let $L=\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n+1}$. Again, define $y_n=x_{n+1}$ and let $\epsilon > 0$.

Then, because the sequence $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges, there exists some $N'$ such that $n'>N'\implies |y_{n'}-L|<\epsilon$.

Let $N = N'+1$, and let $n>N$. Let's call $n' = n - 1$. Then, $|x_n - L| = |x_{n' + 1} - L| = |y_{n'} - L|$. Since $n>N$, we also know that $n-1>N-1$, therefore $n'=n-1>N-1=N'$, so $n'>N'$. which means $|y_{n'}-L|<\epsilon$. We have therefore proven that

> For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $N$ such that $n>N\implies |x_n-L|<\epsilon$

which concludes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that argument is correct. More generally, for the limit behavior of a sequence it does not matter if you remove or change a *finite* number of elements of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this intuitive explanation can help. If a number is a limit of sequence, than infinitely many elements of the sequence are in any (even very small) neighborhood of this number.

Now imagine limit of sequence. If we just throw off $x_n$, it still has infinitely many elements around.